# (LibGDX) Displaying a screenshot from previous FrameBuffer on a Stage

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to get a screenshot to display on the background of a pause menu.

My screenshot method uses `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap()` to get the screenshot; I got it from [here.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot)

My code for the pause screen is as follows:

```
public class CEscapeScreen implements CScreen {

    private final Stage stage;

    private class BGActor extends Actor {
        Pixmap pixmap = CUtil.getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        Texture t = new Texture(pixmap);
        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
            batch.draw(t, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public CEscapeScreen(CGame g) {
        Actor bgActor = new BGActor();

        stage = new Stage();
        final TextButton quitButton = new TextButton("Quit to Main Menu", CUi.getUISkin(), "default");

        ...

        table.add(quitButton);

        stage.addActor(bgActor);
        stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

The `display` method is called every frame by the current `Screen` the program is on.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get a screenshot of the screen before the pause screen stage is drawn, and then draw that screenshot behind the `quitButton`.

Every other `Screen` clears and makes a new `Stage` like this one.

The problem I'm having, is that only the `quitButton` appears on the Escape Menu. Why does this happen?